# Check if an RSA key is correct before calling doFinal?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, encryption

I am trying to create a program that will check digital signature using the `javax.crypto.Cipher` API.

My program works correctly as long as the RSA keys are paired correctly.  However, when I have an incorrect key trying to decrypt the message, I am getting a exception:

> `BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero`

on the call to

```
byte[] signature = cipher.doFinal();
```

I'd like to be able to check if the key will work prior to invoking `doFinal`, or, failing that, exit gracefully.  I've wrapped the `doFinal` in a try/catch block, to try and close my UDP socket, but that's not working.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [`Signature`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) class to handle RSA signature verification.

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA"); // Adjust as necessary
sig.initVerify(publicKey);
sig.update(dataThatWasSigned);

try {
  boolean validSignature = sig.verify(signatureYouReceived);
} catch (SignatureException e) {
  // Graceful handling belongs here...
}
```